# Закрытие окна в расширении chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте ! Пишу расширение для Google Chrome.

Мне нужно открыть страницу, выполнить действия и закрыть ее.

Вод код

`url = "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/" + feed_id + "/";
window.open(url,"Trade","menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
window.close();`

Открывается новая вкладка. Но не закрывается.

Пробовал также `this.close();`, тоже самое.

Как закрыть эту вкладку ?

Comment: Так же рассматривается вариант закрытия через tabId хрома, но это на крайний случай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы же пытаемся закрыть открытое окно, а не наше расширение?)

```
var url = "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/" + feed_id + "/";
var win =     window.open(url,"Trade","menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
win.close();
```

;)